# Segmentation fault reading random lines of text?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, random, return-type

I have read a lot documentation about this subject but i still have some problem about this,ı know what pointer is but when i try to use ı am facing some problem ,at below code,txt file includes just one words at every line.I tried the read random line from text and return to main function cause after i will need this).And i print it in main function ,please can you help me which section should i change in this code?(When ı try to run this the error message is Segmentation fault (core dumped))

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

char word(char *file, char str[], int i);

int main() {
  char buf[512];

  char j = word("words.txt", buf, 512);
  puts(j); // print random num
}

char word(char *file, char str[], int i) {
  int end, loop, line;

  FILE *fd = fopen(file, "r");
  if (fd == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to open file\n");
    return -1;
  }

  srand(time(NULL));
  line = rand() % 100 + 1; // take random num

  for (end = loop = 0; loop < line; ++loop) {
    if (0 == fgets(str, sizeof(str), fd)) { // assign text within a random line to STR
      end = 1;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!end)
    return (char*)str; // return the str pointer
  fclose(fd);
}
```

Comment: `char str` as a function argument is suspicious, as is `sizeof(str)`

Comment: Also why are you opening the file twice?

Comment: You are right it is unnecessary i edited,but i still dont understand what is wrong about this code and i didn't understand why char str is suspicious as an argument ?

Comment: Because it won't contain a string (a word) but just a single character such as `a' or '\n'.

Comment: `fgets` expects a char *, so an address. You are passing a single character, instead. Trying to write to an address tha IS NOT a real address = segfault.

Comment: I edited as you said, at compile time there is 1 warning:returning ‘char *’ from a function with return type ‘char’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   37 |         return  str;//return the str pointer.And seg fault when compile the code again

Comment: I rolled back your edits to a previous revision.  The edit feature isn't intended to modify the code in your question as you receive feedback.  It makes it confusing for anyone coming here in the future reading answers and comments based on code that is no longer there.

Comment: Ok,ı got it.In my edited code was taken 2 parameters which are (char *file, char *str),and after ı changed return value as a pointer(char*)str.Now  there is no warning but still 1 error seg fault.Can you help about my error

Answer (score 0):

You reopened the file, this might be the case. You don't close the file if it returns in if(!end) part the fd is not closed.
And the function takes char but actually needs char *

````
char word(char *file, char str, int i);

int main() {
  char * buf = malloc(sizeof(char)*512);
  char *words = "words.txt";
  char* j = word(words, buf, 512);
  puts(j); // print random num
}

char word(char *file, char str[], int i) { // FIX HERE
  int end, loop, line;

  FILE *fd = fopen(file, "r"); // 
  if (fd == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to open file\n");
    return -1;
  }

  srand(time(NULL));
  line = rand() % 100 + 1; // take random num

  for (end = loop = 0; loop < line; ++loop) {
    if (0 == fgets(str, sizeof(str), fd)) { // MAIN PROBLEM, PUT A CHAR* TO STR. 
      end = 1;
      break;
    }
  }
fclose(fd); // YOU DIDN'T CLOSE IF IT RETURNED BEFORE
  if (!end)
    return str; // return the str pointer

//NOTHING IS RETURNED HERE
return str;
// I guess the problem is here, you return nothing and the function finishes, and you try to write that nothing with puts function which may cause a seg fault.
}```
````

Comment: ı edited char word(char* file,char* str);and return (char*)str but there is still error and i added  else printf("hi"); before close the fd and still seg fault.

Comment: I tried the code and find the mistake! You give a char inside the puts function. I edited the code, try now and please accept my answer as the answer to the question, I need reputations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ı compile it but there is still segmentation error and some warns,which are:initialization of ‘char *’ from ‘char’ makes pointer from integer without a cast(14.13),sizeof’ on array function parameter ‘str’ will return size of ‘char *’, returning ‘char *’ from a function with return type ‘char’ makes integer from pointer without a cast(38.12),returning ‘char *’ from a function with return type ‘char’ makes integer from pointer without a cast(41.8)